# Android - How to apply selectableItemBackground to entire ListView item?

Tags: android

I am new to Android, writing my first app right now. I've got a ListView rendering a series of items, each item having multiple TextViews. I want each item in the ListView to be click-able, and to animate the click. The animation is what I am struggling with.

I have the selectableItemBackground attribute, and it works perfectly on a TextView-by-TextView basis. However, that means that the click animation only appears over that particular TextView, whereas I want it to appear over the entire list item itself.

Here is my Android view. I know that this behavior is caused by me putting the selectableItemBackground attribute on the TextView elements, I just can't figure out where else to put it to achieve the effect I'm going for.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/past_game_update_timestamp"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:padding="@dimen/small_padding"
        android:textSize="@dimen/small_font_size" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/past_game_start_timestamp"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:padding="@dimen/small_padding"
        android:textSize="@dimen/small_font_size" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As part of what I understood from your question. Is that you want your whole view to be having an onClick animation.
For this you have two options :

In most cases, you should apply this functionality in your view XML by specifying the view background as:

1. `?android:attr/selectableItemBackground` for a bounded ripple.
2. `?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless` for a ripple that
   extends beyond the view. It will be drawn upon and bounded by, the nearest parent
   of the view with a non-null background.

> Note: selectableItemBackgroundBorderless is a new attribute introduced
> in API level 21.

Please check with option 2.

Comment: I tried putting #1 on the LinearLayout but it didn't seem to work. Can you show me how it would be applied in the XML?

Comment: NM, I figured it out and posted the full solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after I commented on the above answer, I figured out the rest of it. I needed to make the LinearLayout clickable & focusable, and I needed to disable clickable/focusable on the TextViews. I also needed to set them to duplicateParentState. All of that allows the selectableItemBackground to work on the LinearLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="@dimen/small_padding">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/past_game_update_timestamp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:textSize="@dimen/small_font_size" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/past_game_start_timestamp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:textSize="@dimen/small_font_size" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can move `?android:attr/selectableItemBackground` into the root view of your item layout.

Like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/past_game_update_timestamp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/small_padding"
        android:textSize="@dimen/small_font_size" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/past_game_start_timestamp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/small_padding"
        android:textSize="@dimen/small_font_size" />
</LinearLayout>
```

don't forget to add `android:focusable="true"` and `android:clickable="true"`